# If page content changes height, slide up/down footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

With jQuery available, how would I go about the following:

I have a div on a page, with content inside.  There is no set height to this div however,  it reguarly changes height depending on what the user is searching (content appears/disappears based on whats being typed).

This all works, however the footer doesn't look too good as it jumps to the position as soon as the div changes height.

Is there anyway way I could make it so the footer slides to the position of where it is going too? Rather than jump to it?

I would supply code, but I have no idea how to do this sorry!

My guess: Grab the current height of the div, and when it changes, calculate the difference and move it up?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or some html/css you're currently using?

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#theChangingDivYouMentioned").height();` and slide the footer with `$("#footer").animate();`? You should position the footer absolutely (`position: absolute;`) for this to work. And of course the traditional "welcome to Stackoverflow!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If css3 is acceptable and I understood what you're asking correctly you can just add a transition property such as

```
#content {
    transition: height 2s;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    -moz-transition: height 2s;
    -o-transition: height 2s;
    -khtml-transition: height 2s;
    -ms-transition: height 2s;
}
```

If not you can use jquery as in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YLKf9/1/

Comment: Hmm okay thanks for the comments, I think I went about it the wrong way... I have a div, and if I type something into a box, some elements in the box go to "display:hidden;", and therefore the div shrinks in height in one big go, which means the footer follows it.

I think I need to ask, how do I get the div size to hold its size, even if elements are removed, and then "animate" to the size it should be, so the footer slides too?

Comment: This should work for that exact purpose you mentioned given you don't switch the container div's height either from js or css from auto to a fixed amount or viceversa. Having height: auto for the div both before and after modifying it's content's properties will cause an animation with the code I provided on css3 compatible browsers.

Comment: @Alias I added a jquery version to my answer, just in case